# Avro size too big?

Tags: protocol-buffers, avro

I do some research on what is the best data exchange format in my company. For the moment I compare Protocol Buffers and Apache Avro.
Request are exchanging between components in our architecture, but only one by one. And my impression is that Avro is very bigger thant Protocol Buffers when transport only one by one. In the avro file, the schema is always present and our request has a lot of optional field, so our schema is ver big even if our data are small.
But I don't know if I missed something, it's written everywhere than avro is smaller, but for us it seems that we have to put one thousand requests in one file for having PBuffers and avro's size equals.
I missed something or my thoughts are true?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It's not at all surprising that two serialization formats would produce basically equal sizes. These aren't compression algorithms, they're just structure. For any decent format, the vast majority of your data is going to be *your data*; the structure around it (which is the part that varies depending on serialization format) ought to be negligible. The size of *your data* simply doesn't change regardless of the serialization format around it.

Note also that anyone who claims that one format is always smaller than another is either lying or doesn't know what they're talking about. Every format has strengths and weaknesses, so the "best" format totally depends on the use case. It's important to test each format using your own data to find out what is best for you -- and it sounds like you are doing just that, which is great! If Protobuf and Avro came out equal size in your test, then you should choose based on other factors. You might want to test encoding/decoding speed, for example.